# Does increasing ram reduce memory usage percentage in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, memory, virtual-memory, memory-usage

I have i5-9300h processor and 8bg of ram on my laptop and recently have noticed that Chrome and apparently Desktop Windows Manager accounts for maximum memory usage in my task manager. So upgrading my ram to 16gb help or is it something that can't be helped?

Comment: it helps, it reduces percentage of memory used.  8GB is very low. You should have 16GB or some have even 32GB if their system supports it.

Comment: Memory usage should remain unchanged. But now that you have more memory, the percentage used will be lower.

Comment: Chrome and Edge both use more memory as you use more tabs. Many tabs = lots of memory  used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're maxing out on RAM, then adding more will definitely help.  As other comments have noted, the more tabs used, the more RAM utilized.  Chrome is definitely a RAM hog.  Upgrading RAM is one of the most common, easy, and inexpensive ways to give your computer a boost if you're running into that particular wall.

Unrelated, but just in case you're unaware, if your machine is still using a hard drive, it's likely a bottle neck in performance all on its own.  Switching to SSD storage is another relatively inexpensive upgrade that will give you a nice performance boost in some areas.